# RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.OperationInterruptedException when I try to run the masstransit sample application Sample-Courier

Tags: masstransit

Here is some detail information:
I am running Visual Studio 2015 - clone the code from GitHub:
https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-Courier.git

and I setup my rabbitmq in one of my hyper-v virtual machine (ipaddress: 192.168.1.36) - and I was able to access the management console through http://192.168.1.36:15672/

But when I ran the sample application (client project) the application throw an exception:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.OperationInterruptedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: The AMQP operation was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by Peer, code=540, text="NOT_IMPLEMENTED - global=true", classId=60, methodId=10, cause=
```

Comment: What version of RabbitMQ server did you install?

Comment: I just checked the RabbitMQ version it is 3.2.3 -  I was using apt-get to install that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on Chris comments, I checked the version I installed on my Ubuntu VM, it was 3.2.3, and I found that is the root cause.

So basically the apt was pretty old for rabbitmq - the newest version should be 3.6.0, since I am not very familiar how to install a deb, so I just used apt-get to install that.

After I uninstalled old version (3.2.3), and download the deb file 3.6.0, then installed it again - everything worked as expected.